# Joda Time to Java Time Migration show different result while migration

Tags: java, java-8, jodatime

Given the following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter _timestampFomatNYCJoda = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd HHmmss.SSS").withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York"));
     DateTimeFormatter _timestampFomatNYC = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd HHmmss.SSS").withZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
     LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
     org.joda.time.LocalDateTime jodaLocalDateTime = new org.joda.time.LocalDateTime();
     System.out.println("System Time " + new Date());
     System.out.println("Java Version " +  localDateTime.format(_timestampFomatNYC));
     System.out.println("Joda Version " +  _timestampFomatNYCJoda.print(jodaLocalDateTime.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC)));
}
```

Why does the Java Version and Joda Version dont match ? I am running this on IST clock.

Below is the output

```
System Time Fri Mar 27 17:01:33 IST 2020
Java Version 20200327 170133.933
Joda Version 20200327 130133.938
```

Comment: Because the should.  You've taken 2 different time snapshots between `localDateTime` and `jodaLocalDateTime`.  The diference between 1700 and 1300 is because Eastern time is 5 hours off UTC time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce your results. I can also explain them. Joda-Time and java.time have been designed to behave differently in this case. Let’s look at them in turn.

**Joda-Time**

In Joda-Time `DateTimeFormatter.withZone()` gives you a formatter with an *override zone*, that is, a zone that will *always* be used for formatting dates and times. In other words, any date and time will be converted to this zone for printing. The documentation says:

> When printing, this zone will be used in preference to the zone from
>   the datetime that would otherwise be used.

When you do `new org.joda.time.LocalDateTime()`, you are getting a `LocalDateTime` representing the current date and time in your default time zone. The `Local` in some class names means *without time zone or offset from UTC*. I figure that you must have got a value equal to `2020-03-27T17:01:33.938`.

Apparently what happens when you format a `LocalDateTime` with a formatter with an override zone, is that the formatter assumes that your `LocalDateTime` is in UTC (which yours isn’t) and converts it from there, in your case to America/New_York time zone. Since summer time (DST) is in effect in New York, the offset is -04:00, so 17:01 becomes 13:01.

This is the wrong result. When the time is 17:01 in your time zone, it is not 17:01 UTC, so the conversion is based on a false premise. It is also not 13:01 in New York, so the converted result is telling a lie.

**java.time**

With java.time setting an override zone on a formatter works similarly for formatting, but with a difference that matters here: the override zone is only used when printing a date-time object that identifies an instant (a point in time). From the docs:

> When formatting, if the temporal object contains an instant, then it
>   will be converted to a zoned date-time using the override zone.
>   Whether the temporal is an instant is determined by querying the
>   `INSTANT_SECONDS` field. If the input has a chronology then it will be
>   retained unless overridden. If the input does not have a chronology,
>   such as Instant, then the ISO chronology will be used.
>
> … In all other cases, the override zone is added to the temporal,
>   replacing any previous zone, but without changing the date/time.

Again `LocalDateTime.now()` gives you the current date and time of day (a few milliseconds earlier than the query through Joda-Time), `2020-03-27T17:01:33.933`. `Local` still means without offset or time zone.

Because your `LocalDateTIme` hasn’t got offset or time zone, it cannot identify an unambigous point in time, an instant. Therefore when formatting it neither the date nor the time of day is changed. And since your format pattern contains no time zone or offset, none is printed. So you just get the date and time in your time zone (not in New York), `20200327 170133.933`.

**To get the date and time in New York time zone**

```
    DateTimeFormatter timestampFormat
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd HHmmss.SSS");
    ZonedDateTime timeInNy = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
    System.out.println(timeInNy.format(timestampFormat));
```

When I ran this code just now, the output was:

> 20200327 122359.683

**Documentation links**

- Joda-Time [`DateTimeFormatter.withZone()`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withZone-org.joda.time.DateTimeZone-)
- java.time [`DateTimeFormatter.withZone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withZone(java.time.ZoneId))